# Can I automatically login to ssh using passwords from OS X keychain?

Tags: macos, ssh

I need to login to an ssh server which doesn't support key based authentication. And I don't want to type the passwords every time.

I am using OS X Lion (10.7.2). I have added the passwords to the OS X keychain[1]. Now I can retrieve the password automatically from the keychain using `/usr/bin/security`, however I can't find a way to send this password to the ssh prompt.

I also tried [`sshpass`](http://sourceforge.net/projects/sshpass/). However when I try to run it ssh exits with the following error:

```
ssh_askpass: exec(/usr/libexec/ssh-askpass): No such file or directory
Permission denied, please try again.
ssh_askpass: exec(/usr/libexec/ssh-askpass): No such file or directory
Permission denied, please try again.
ssh_askpass: exec(/usr/libexec/ssh-askpass): No such file or directory
Permission denied (publickey,password).
```

Is there anyway I can login to this server without having to enter the password every time?

**Notes**

1. The scheme I use in keychain looks like this

   - Kind: Internet password
   - Account: username
   - Where: ssh://server-name

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found a solution (thanks to Daniel Beck for providing the key info needed for this). Note that I have only tested this with OS X Lion 10.7.2. If this doesn't work for you, try Daniel's solution.

First we need to set the `SSH_ASKPASS` environment variable -- its value should be the path to a program which prints the password to standard output. To get the password from the keychain, this is what it needs to look like (I call it `get-ssh-password.sh`):

```
#!/bin/bash

/usr/bin/security find-internet-password -a "$SSH_PASSWORD_USER" -s "$SSH_PASSWORD_HOSTNAME" -r "ssh " -g 2>&1 1>/dev/null | cut -d\" -f2
```

A couple of points to note:

1. This assumes that you have stored the password in the keychain in the way I have described in the question
2. The program given in `SSH_ASKPASS` will be called without any arguments; so we use environment variables to pass the user and hostname to it.

Now we can set `SSH_PASSWORD_USER` and `SSH_PASSWORD_HOSTNAME` and run `sshpass` to login to our server.

I created another script, `ssh-kcpass`, to do this:

```
#!/bin/bash

export SSH_ASKPASS=~/bin/get-ssh-password.sh
export SSH_PASSWORD_USER=$(echo "$1" | cut -d@ -f1)
export SSH_PASSWORD_HOSTNAME=$(echo "$1" | cut -d@ -f2)

sshpass ssh "$1"
```

To login to the ssh server without typing any password, you just need to run `ssh-kcpass user@hostname`.

Comment: How to make this to work in `macOS >= 10.13`

Comment: I assume this as a "non interactive" SSH session?

Answer (score 13):

### Non-interactive SSH sessions

If you don't need to have an interactive session on the remote server, you can execute `ssh` in an environment without `tty`, e.g. as part of a *Run Shell Script* action in *Automator*.

You need to create a program that when called prints the password to standard out, e.g. the following bash script you need to make executable using `chmod +x pwd.sh`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
echo "password"
```

Then, set the `SSH_ASKPASS` environment variable to the path to this program, and then run `ssh` in the Automator action, like this:

```
export SSH_ASKPASS=/Users/danielbeck/pwd.sh
ssh user@hostname ls
```

---

When there is no `tty`, but `SSH_ASKPASS` and `DISPLAY` (for X11, set by default) are set, SSH executes the program specified by `SSH_ASKPASS` and uses its output as password. This is intended to be used in graphical environments, so that a window can pop up asking for your password. In this case, we just skipped the window, returning the password from our program. You can use `security` to read from your keychain instead, like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
security find-generic-password -l password-item-label -g 2>&1 1>/dev/null | cut -d'"' -f2
```

`ls` (on the `ssh` command line) is the command executed when `ssh` has logged in, and its output is printed in Automator. You can, of course, redirect it to a file to log output of the program you start.

---

### Interactive SSH sessions using `sshpass`

I downloaded, compiled and installed `sshpass` and it worked perfectly. Here's what I did:

1. Get the Apple developer tools
2. Download and open `sshpass-1.05.tar.gz`
3. Open a shell to the directory `sshpass-1.05`
4. Run `./configure`
5. Run `make`
6. Run `make install` (you might need `sudo` for it)

Now the program is installed to `/usr/local/bin/sshpass`. Execute using a line like the following:

```
sshpass -pYourPassword ssh username@hostname
```

You can read the password from `security` just before doing that, and use it like this:

```
SSHPASSWORD=$( security find-generic-password -l password-item-label -g 2>&1 1>/dev/null | cut -d'"' -f2 )
sshpass -p"$SSHPASSWORD" ssh username@hostname
```

Wrap this in a shell function and you can just type e.g. `ssh-yourhostname` to connect, having it retrieve and enter the password automatically.

Comment: Hi, I have upvoted your answer since it led me to the solution. However, what you described here didn't exactly work (this might be specific to Lion's version of ssh) 1) For non-interactive sessions, ssh still asked me for a password, and after I entered it, I got `STDIN is not a terminal`. 2) For interactive sessions with `sshpass`, the `-p` option apparently doesn't do anything. But running `sshpass` while `SSH_ASKPASS` is set does work!

Comment: @ChaitanyaGupta Odd. It worked for me non-interactively from within Automator on Lion. Regarding that second issue, it's possible I had a dirty shell session at that point, I'm not sure anymore. +1 to you, and thanks for adding your solution to the site.

Comment: My bad (regarding 1) -- I was trying to run the non-interactive session in the terminal and not Automator. I tried it in Automator now, and I still get `STDIN is not a terminal` error. However, I wasn't prompted for any password this time; I do believe `SSH_ASKPASS` is working in the Automator since, if I make the file in `SSH_ASKPASS` return the wrong password, I get a `Permission denied, please try again.` error.

Comment: For the last examples note that under Unix like OSes command line arguments and environment variables can be visible to other users on the system, so this is not secure in a sensitive multi user environment.

Comment: @DanielBeck any Idea how to make this to work in `macOs >= 10.13`

Comment: great solution, but your means of parsing out just the password from the `security` utility is now a bit out of date.  The `-w` option will just return the password directly.  So you can replace all of `-g 2>&1 1>/dev/null | cut -d'"' -f2` with `-w`.  Here's the full example using this:


`SSHPASSWORD=$( security find-generic-password -l password-item-label -w );`
  `sshpass -p"$SSHPASSWORD" ssh username@hostname`

Comment: @Chris To clarify, it works as written, but has more text than necessary to copy & paste? I'm fine with that if there's a chance it's more compatible.

Comment: Note that all of the non-`SSH_ASKPASS` solutions seem to place the password in the arguments, which is not secure. See this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6607675/shell-script-password-security-of-command-line-parameters

Comment: sshpass installation instructions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32255660/how-to-install-sshpass-on-mac and it works great

Answer (score 0):

With Open ssh 1.8.4+ you can use SSH_ASKPASS with normal interactive usage (some of this from other answers and comments):

```
$ brew install openssh # install 1.8.4+ if you don't have it, test current with ssh -V
```

Create some file `/foo` with your equivalent of this content

```
security find-generic-password -l your-password-item-label -w
```

and make it executable, use it

```
$ SSH_ASKPASS=/foo SSH_ASKPASS_REQUIRE=force ssh user@hostname
```

ref: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/603217/8337

You could put the env. variables in your ~/.zshrc if you always need just the same password.

Answer (score -3):

Hi there people I came across this topic looking for some other thing but ...
Don’t know if I’m missing something here... but your approach seems odd to me. why not just use public key authentication...
Generate an rsa key
$ ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 2048 -C ‘email/id’

Ideally you’d use once the ssh-copy-id user@host and authenticate with password once to install the key on the other server, or use any kind of script or authomation tool to deploy the key to ~/.ssh/authorized_keys on the other host (for the user you want to login to)
If done with the command manually you then have to edit /etc/ssh/sshd_config accordingly and w automation (chef, ansible) you’d push the full condiga for desired state.

The key that matters to distribute is id_rsa.pub, keep the private key secure

To use keychain to authenticate to hosts in an automatic straightforward fashion edit on your machine the ~/.ssh/config and add:

Host *
UseKeychain yes

Look for more info on ssh config file options hope any of this comes handy

Comment: Read the first sentence of the question body: ‘‘I need to login to an ssh server which *doesn't support key based authentication.*’’

Comment: Hi Scott I think you also missed the part where he says he doesn’t want to type the password everytime, which means he is doing it.

Comment: No, I didn’t miss that. Why would you believe that I did?