# Specify passphrase when invoking ssh?

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, ssh

I'm trying to run a remote command using SSH in a script. Host1 is connecting to Host2 to run a command.

I've setup the public keys between the two hosts so I don't need to use a password to make the ssh connection.

However, the key for Host1 was generated using a passphrase so SSH is still prompting for that passphrase when I try to SSH.

Is there any way to specify this passphrase so that my script can execute the command?

I know I can re-generate the key and choose not to use a passphrase; but I'm wondering if it is at all possible to use a passphrase **and** run ssh from a script?

---

I tried setting the `SSH_ASKPASS` environment variable as described [here](https://superuser.com/a/393541/236843) but that did not work. I'm assuming it only uses that variable for the password and not for the **passphrase**?

Comment: If you start up an `ssh-agent` and then `ssh-add` your key, you'll have to give the passphrase once, but the subsequent `ssh` commands will not require interaction.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I automatically login to ssh using passwords from OS X keychain?](http://superuser.com/questions/393506/can-i-automatically-login-to-ssh-using-passwords-from-os-x-keychain)

Comment: @glenn jackamn said it all. Your either want manual check for password every time (and no password/passphrase in script). Or no manual prompt, use a passphrase less key pair (and automatic connection for whoever hijack computer/user).

Comment: If the script needs to run without a passphrase then effectively it means that you need to unencrypted key somewhere accessible to it.  If you want to maintain the passphrase to stop user access while allowing the script `ssh-agent` is probably best, or set up a separate key the script has permission to use but the user doesn't.  Won't stop a root user, though.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to create scripts using the [expect](http://linux.die.net/man/1/expect) command. It was specifically designed to handle these situations.

Note that you will have to store your passphrase somewhere in clear text in your script.

I use it to log in to some remote servers without having to type my password for the remote machines.